# Can I install Windows after Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, windows-8, bootloader

I'm thinking about if Windows can be installed after Ubuntu like a Dual Boot thing...

Please tell me if its possible.. without losing any Ubuntu files

Anyway I'm a new to **Ubuntu**

Comment: probably windows boot-loader do not support/allow installed Ubuntu loader and hence after installing windows (after Ubuntu) [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to install **windows** on a machine that already possess **Ubuntu**.
Yes it is possible. But you will have to shrink your **Ubuntu** partition first in order to make some space for **windows**. Use **gparted** to shrink the partitions easily (especially if you are new).
Then the **windows installer** should propose you an option to install alongside the other systems.
However, I don't know what will happen to the **grub** bootloader. You will probably have a **windows** equivalent to **grub**.

Comment: Windows bootloader wont recognise Ubuntu, so grub will have to be reinstall/repaired after.

Comment: To do this, boot from a Ubuntu live system, start GParted and set the boot flag from the Windows partition to the Ubuntu partition.